# Moving StateT into and out of IO

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm sure I must be missing something.

I'm new to Haskell and the curve is very steep. I'm reaching the point in my toy project where I really want to use a State monad to avoid passing a thousand arguments everywhere. I'm having trouble understanding how to pass that State monad from IO into pure code. Something conceptually like this (except with StateT instead of ExceptT):

```
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.Identity

type PlayM = Except String 
type PlayMIO = ExceptT String IO

puree :: String -> PlayM String
puree = return . ("bb"++)

impuree :: String -> PlayMIO String
impuree s = do
  a <- return $ runIdentity $ runExceptT $ puree s
  return $ "aa" ++ a

main = do
  runExceptT $ impuree "foo"
  putStrLn "hi"
```

except this doesn't compile, giving me something like this:

```
play.hs:15:20:
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’
            with actual type ‘Either String String’
In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘a’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘"aa" ++ a’
```

I understand now why this doesn't compile and why the types are what they are, but for the life of me, I cannot understand how to do this. This feels like it shouldn't be hard, but my intuition in Haskell is far from accurate.

Thanks for your help!

-g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate approach is to simply make your `puree` and `impuree` operations type-class polymorphic. This is the usual `mtl` way: require some classes, then somewhere at the top-level pick a concrete monad that instantiates all the appropriate classes. Thus:

```
import Control.Monad.Except
import Control.Monad.Identity

type PlayM = Except String 
type PlayMIO = ExceptT String IO

puree :: Monad m => String -> m String
puree = return . ("bb"++)

impuree :: Monad m => String -> m String
impuree s = do
  a <- puree s
  return $ "aa" ++ a

main = do
  runExceptT $ impuree "foo"
  putStrLn "hi"
```

In this example, your code is especially uninteresting, because you didn't use any of the special powers of `IO` or `ExceptT`. Here's how it might look if you had:

```
-- in particular, puree :: String -> PlayM String
puree :: MonadError String m => String -> m String
puree "heck" = throwError "Watch your language!"
puree s = return ("bb" ++ s)

-- in particular, impuree :: String -> PlayMIO String
impuree :: (MonadError String m, MonadIO m) => String -> m String
impuree s = do
  s' <- puree s
  liftIO . putStrLn $ "hah! what kind of input is " ++ s ++ "?!"
  return ("aa" ++ s)

main = do
  runExceptT (impuree "foo")
  putStrLn "hi"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a great response, too, and educational for me.  It looks like I need FlexibleContexts in order to put "MonadError String m" into the context of puree? Any downside to that?

Comment: @GeorgeMadrid Practically speaking, there's no downside. Hypothetically, this would rule out using your code with compilers that don't support that extension; since GHC is such a powerhouse in the Haskell compiler domain, I wouldn't worry about that unless you're already planning to use a niche compiler. There aren't many technical downsides, either: the restrictions that extension relaxes were put in place to make language implementation easier before it was really known how feasible typeclasses were as a language feature at all. With what we know now I think different choices would be made.

Comment: I am fascinated with how quickly the understanding of functional programming in general and Haskell in particular are changing. Any book you read is already out of date. And I am amazed at the power of the Haskell type inference engine and how it is more that a convenience. I'm learning that it is a fundamental tool of working with Haskell. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

You're close. Let's follow the types with type holes (`_`s):

```
impuree :: String -> PlayMIO String
impuree s = do
  a <- _ . runIdentity . runExceptT $ puree s
  return $ "aa" ++ a
```

This tells us we need a type:

```
Test.hs:15:8:
    Found hole ‘_’
      with type: m0 (Either String String) -> ExceptT String IO [Char]
    Where: ‘m0’ is an ambiguous type variable
    Relevant bindings include
      s :: String (bound at Test.hs:13:9)
      impuree :: String -> PlayMIO String (bound at Test.hs:13:1)
    In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘_’
    In the expression: _ . return . runIdentity . runExceptT
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      a <- _ . return . runIdentity . runExceptT $ puree s
```

Now, we have something that can turn a `m (Either e b)` into an `ExceptT e m b`:

```
ExceptT :: m (Either e b) -> ExceptT e m b
```

Applying that, we get the correct answer:

```
impuree :: String -> PlayMIO String
impuree s = do
  a <- ExceptT . return . runIdentity . runExceptT $ puree s
  return $ "aa" ++ a
```

If we look at the docs, we can see that the pattern `ExceptT . f . runExceptT` is abstracted with the function

```
mapExceptT :: (m (Either e a) -> n (Either e' b)) -> ExceptT e m a -> ExceptT e' n b
```

In our case, the `m` is `Identity` and the `n` is `IO`. Using this, we get:

```
impuree :: String -> PlayMIO String
impuree s = do
  a <- mapExceptT (return . runIdentity) $ puree s
  return $ "aa" ++ a
```

### Abstracting the pattern

This would probably be overkill here, but it is worth noting that there is a package called [`mmorph`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph) which makes it nicer to work with monad morphisms (transformations from one monad to another). This package has a function [`generalize :: Monad m => Identity a -> m a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#v:generalize) which we can use:

```
impuree :: String -> PlayMIO String
impuree s = do
  a <- mapExceptT generalize $ puree s
  return $ "aa" ++ a
```

### A further generalization

While we're talking about `mmorph`, we may as well use the more general form:

```
impuree :: String -> PlayMIO String
impuree s = do
  a <- hoist generalize $ puree s
  return $ "aa" ++ a
```

[`hoist`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html#v:hoist) generalizes `mapExceptT` to any monad transformer-like thing where you can apply a monad morphism to the underlying monad:

```
hoist :: (MFunctor t, Monad m) => (forall a. m a -> n a) -> t m b -> t n b
```

Everything after the first correct answer here is just bonus stuff and it isn't necessary to understand it in order to understand and use the solution. It could come in handy at some point though, which is why I included it. Recognizing the general pattern of monad morphisms saves time, but you can always do things more explicitly without that additional level of abstraction.

Comment: Fantastic. Excellent explanation with extras. Thanks. You've helped my learning as well as answering my question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `EitherT` crept in by mistake.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks! I had a feeling that would happen. If only that were the actual name...

Comment: How did we end up with a name that wasn't that?

Comment: [`EitherT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/either/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html)